# Class of $p$-supersolvable group is saturated formation.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

I want to show that the class of $p$-supersolvable groups is a saturated formation.

I only have the definition of $p$-supersolvable. What do I do?

A group is **$p$-supersolvable** iff every chief factor either has order $p$ or order coprime to $p$. A **chief factor** of $G$ is a quotient $H/K$ where (a) $H,K \unlhd G$, (b) $H < K$, and (c) if $H \leq L < K$ and $L \unlhd G$, then $H=L$.

A class $\mathcal{F}$ of groups is a **saturated formation** if

1) if $G \in \mathcal{F}$ and $H \lhd G$ then $G/H \in \mathcal{F}$.

2) if $G/M, G/N \in \mathcal{F}$ for $M,N \lhd G$, then $G/M\cap N \in \mathcal{F}$.

3) if $G/\phi(G) \in \mathcal{F}$ then $G\in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Well the first step would be to find the definition of saturated formation, too...

Comment: i know the definition of saturated formation.

Comment: Include it then please

Comment: You should include the definitions of both $p$-supersolvable and saturated formation. I know roughly what they mean, but I would want to check the definitions before trying to answer your question.

Comment: I don't think my previous residual methods are particularly suited to this question, but I'll mention that the $p$-supersolvable groups again form a subgroup-closed Fitting formation, so condition (2) can be proven by showing $p$-supersolvable is closed under direct products and subgroups.

Comment: Saturation is a theorem of Huppert, http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=199264. He gives a proof in Kapitel VI, §8, Satz 8.4 / 8.6a page 713.