# What is the purpose of the almost maximal and $ p $-supersolvable subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $ H \unlhd G $ such that $ G/H $ is supersolvable. Suppose that there is an element $ y \in H $ such that $ H = \langle y \rangle L $ for any almost maximal subgroup L of $ H $; then $ G $ is supersolvable.

What is the purpose of the almost maximal subgroup?

$ p $-solvable group is defined by Robinson's book. But What is $ p $-supersolvable group? Search but I did not found.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430742/g-is-p-supersoluble-iff-g-m-p-for-each-maximal-subgroup-m-in-g

Comment: very thanks. What is almost maximal subgroup ?