# Definition of $ p $-supersoluble group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I was searching for definition of $ p $-supersoluble group but not find definition. Please help me.

Comment: In mathematics, a group is supersolvable (or supersoluble) if it has an invariant normal series where all the factors are cyclic groups. Supersolvability is stronger than the notion of solvability.
[link-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group). Related question [p-supersolvable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426776/class-of-p-supersolvable-group-is-saturated-formation)

Comment: hi You're Iranian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that every chief factor of the group either has order $p$ or it has order coprime to $p$. So a (finite) group is supersoluble if and only if it is $p$-supersoluble for all primes $p$.

Comment: I search by don't find reference for this " (finite) group is supersoluble if and only if it is $ p $-supersoluble for all primes $ p $. Please help me to find .

Comment: It's very easy to prove so there is no need for a reference.

Comment: How do i prove? " A group $ G $ is said to be $ p $-supersoluble if every chief
factor of $ G $ of order different from $ p $ is a $ p^{\prime} $ -group" ( This is Definition $ 1\cdot 9\cdot 1 $ of  The Theory of Classes of Groups  By Guo Wenbin )

Comment: It  is right for any prime number $ p $ or for $ p $ that $ p \mid \vert G \vert $ ?

Comment: The following three conditions are equivalent for a finite group $G$. (i) $G$ is supersoluble. (ii) $G$ is $p$-supersoluble for all primes $p$. (iii) $G$ is $p$-supersoluble for all primes $p$ that divide $|G|$. The proof is completely straightforward.

Comment: I am confused. In some reference, for example Rose is said " A group is said to be supersoluble if it has a normal series all of whose factors 
are cyclic."  But in your definition is said every chief factor.

Comment: What do you mean by "your definition"? I haven't given a definition. I am just using the standard definition of supersoluble groups, which is the one you are using from Rose. I am sorry but I cannot help you any further with this!